# Error On Expect Script

Tags: ssh, scripting, expect

I keep getting an error on this after sending the new password. It will change the password, but not do the rest of the script. Any ideas why it keeps erroring out. I wrote a very similar script for a different device and it works prefect, but the stuff after changing the password is not needed on that device. This device will not save the password after reboot if the rest is not completed. Doing it manually through ssh works just fine so its not the cmds that is the problem, it's something with the script.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout -1
    #Edit for User
    set user user
    #Edit for Old Password
    set old oldpassword
    #Edit for New Password
    set new newpassword
    #get IP List from iplist.txt
    set f [open "/iplist.txt"]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    foreach line [split $data \n] {
            if {$line eq {}} continue
            spawn ssh $user@$line
            expect "assword:"
            send "$old\r"
            sleep 10
            send "passwd $user\r"
            expect "assword:"
            send "$new\r"
            expect "assword:"
            send "$new\r"
            sleep 10
            send "grep -v users.1.password= /tmp/system.cfg > /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
            sleep 10
            send "echo users.1.password=`grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print \$2}'` >> /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
            sleep 10
            send "cp /tmp/system.cfg.new /tmp/system.cfg\r"
            sleep 10
            send "save && reboot\r"
            close
            expect eof
    }
```

The full script is alot bigger with with fail-safes if the device does not respond to ssh or the original password is wrong. That one won't work though until I figure out what is wrong with this portion. I just slimmed it down to figure out where the problem is happening. Also this line seems to be the issue as it does create the system.config.new on the line before it:

```
            send "echo users.1.password=`grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print \$2}'` >> /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
```

It was and works in ssh as this:

```
            send "echo users.1.password=`grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $2}'` >> /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
```

But sends an error because of the $2 then is view-able by expect. I was told that putting a \$2 would make it only view-able to the remote shell. Any help would be great.

Originally it had expect "star" instead of the sleep cmds. I have been trying tons of stuff out on this script and once I get it to run incorporate it in my full script. The reason I am using sleep is because "star" doesn't seem to match output and fails on the second send $new/r. With sleep it has made it alot farther. I do have a correction though. It is actually making it right up to send "save && reboot\r". I am going to eventually use your $prompt suggestion from my other question in place of sleep or expect "star". With debug on this is where it throws the error:

```
    send: sending "save && reboot\r" to { exp4 }
    expect: spawn id exp4 not open
        while executing
    "expect eof"
        ("foreach" body line 21)
        invoked from within
    "foreach line [split $data \n] {
            if {$line eq {}} continue
            spawn ssh $user@$line
            expect "assword:"
            send "$old\r"
            sleep 3
            send "passwd $user\r"
            e..."
        (file "./ubnt.sh" line 15)
```

The "save && reboot\r" will kick out the ssh connection after it saves the settings, but it doesn't seem to be getting that far. Is there an issue with &&, maybe I need to /&&.

Comment: After each `send` command, `expect ` for the prompt. Without which you are making room for uninvited guests such as these kinds of errors may be.

Comment: Added some more info on this one if you can take a look at it.

Comment: I tried splitting up save and reboot as 2 send cmds and it will save the settings but error after sending reboot cmd and not reboot the device. Any idea y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interact instead of close and expect eof is the answer I will update with full script when it's done. Here is the working UBNT password change script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 30
    #Edit for User
    set user user
    #Edit for Old Password
    set old oldpassword
    #Edit for New Password
    set new newpassword
    #get IP List from iplist.txt
    set f [open "/iplist.txt"]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    foreach line [split $data \n] {
            if {$line eq {}} continue
            spawn ssh $user@$line
            expect {
                    "assword:" {
                            send "$old\r"
                            expect {
                                    "assword:" {
                                                    close
                                                    continue
                                                    }}
                            expect {
                                    "*" {
                                            send "passwd $user\r"
                                            expect "*assword:*"
                                            send "$new\r"
                                            expect "*assword:*"
                                            send "$new\r"
                                            expect "*"
                                            send "grep -v users.1.password= /tmp/system.cfg > /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
                                            expect "*"
                                            send "echo users.1.password=`grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print \$2}'` >> /tmp/system.cfg.new\r"
                                            expect "*"
                                            send "cp /tmp/system.cfg.new /tmp/system.cfg\r"
                                            expect "*"
                                            send "save && reboot\r"
                                            interact
                                            continue
                                            }}}}
            expect {
                    "*" {
                            close
                            continue
                            }}
            expect eof
    }
```

Here is the script for Mikrotik passwords:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 30
    #Edit for User
    set user user
    #Edit for Old Password
    set old oldpassword
    #Edit for New Password
    set new newpassword
    #get IP List from iplist.txt
    set f [open "/iplist.txt"]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    foreach line [split $data \n] {
            if {$line eq {}} continue
            spawn -noecho ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $user@$line
            expect {
                    "assword:" {
                            send "$old\r"
                            expect {
                                    "assword:" {
                                                    close
                                                    continue
                                                    }}
                            expect {
                                    "*" {
                                            send "user set $user password=$new\r"
                                            expect ">"
                                            send "quit\r"
                                            close
                                            continue
                                            }}}}
            expect {
                    "*" {
                            close
                            continue
                            }}
            expect eof
    }
```

Dinesh mentioned that I should not use "star" in my expect commands and said that instead use:

```
    set prompt "#|%|>|\\\$ $"
```

And:

```
    expect -re $prompt
```

Which I will probably change. The scripts also move onto next IP in list if the device cannot be reached via ssh or if the oldpassword does not work for the device. The only other change I plan to make on both is to have it create 3 log files listing successful ips, wrong password ips, and cant reach ips. This should only be one more command before each continue, but haven't yet researched how to output a variable to a local log file.

Thanks for your help on this Dinesh.